# Encoding problem when writing to a file in x86

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I'm a new to x86 and currently writing a program where I need to write a file after doing some operations with data I read from a file, but I am facing problems when I write the result to a file, because it is writing with some weird enconding.

Here I reserve the space I am going to need to store the result and the output file:

```
section .data
     new_file db "new_file.txt", 0 

section .bss
     data resb 4
```

The code that writes data to a file called *new_file.txt*:

```
mov rax, SYS_OPEN
mov rdi, new_file
mov rsi, O_CREAT + O_WRONLY
mov rdx, 0644o
syscall

push rax
mov rdi, rax
mov rax, SYS_WRITE
mov rsi, data
mov rdx, 4
syscall

mov rax, SYS_CLOSE
pop rdi
syscall
```

For example, assume that I want to do some addition and then store the result in *data* to write it later:

```
mov rax, 0xF
add rax, 0x1
mov [data], rax
```

in this case the data would have a value of 0x10 and when I check the file generated I get something like this:

[image]

I'm lost since I don't seem to find anything about encoding in x86, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's no encoding, you're just copying 4 bytes from `data` section to the file. It's just binary data.

Comment: Use `hexdump -C` to see what binary data you wrote to the file.  (Although obviously it's a little-endian `0x10`, i.e. `10 00 00 00` in this case.)  Use `strace ./my_program` to see what system calls your program makes.  BTW, you haven't shown a declaration for a `data` label anywhere in your code; is it an implicitly-declared symbol at the start of the `.data` section, or is this just not quite a [mcve]?

Comment: @PeterCordes my mistake, I edited the first block of code to show where data is declared.

Comment: Also related: [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894)

Comment: You’re storing rax, which is 8 bytes, into data, which is only 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Consider for a moment a file that has this content, viewed in hexedit let's say.

```
ADDR  00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07  08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
------------------------------------------------------
 00   0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 F0 9D 90 98 F0
 10   9F 84 09 09 10 00 00 00  03 7C 2D 1A 0A 0A 0A 0A
```

Dumping to console with **CAT** tries display what it thinks is UTF-8 text.

[image]

However, if you look at the same thing using a text editor then;
[image]
or
[image]
So your data was written to file correctly, but the means by which you want to view it is not compatible with the result your expecting. I believe there are applications for Linux, that will display arrays of bytes/words/dwords or qwords and even structures, somewhat analogous to **hexedit**

Comment: yup, classic Unix `od` has hexdump format options, or `hexdump -C` is easy to remember for byte dumps with a printable-ASCII sidebar.

Comment: `cat` doesn't try to interpret file contents, it just writes data to the output.  In this case the output is your terminal, and *your terminal* is normally set to UTF-8 mode.  So its your terminal, not cat, that's treating the binary data as text in some charset.  You can use `cat -v` to show "non-printing" characters as control / meta escape codes.